# Find Terms Associated with an Event

Tags: machine-learning

Sorry, this probably a very easy problem with what I hope is a very generic solution. But I can't think of the right way to formulate it. Hence my google searches aren't getting me anywhere.

I have all procedure billing codes for my cohort. Let A = {(code, count)} be codes filed on the day a certain adverse event took place and let B = {(code, count)} be codes that were recorded on days when the adverse event did not take place.

I want to isolate codes related to A by findings terms that are much more likely to be recorded in A than in B. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could train a binary classifier. Encode each entry in your data as 
$x_i = (\text{code, count, other description})$ and $y_i=1$ if the entry belongs to A and $y_i=0$ if it belongs to B. As a first step, you could try fitting a [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).